# Why min-height style have no effect for a div

Tags: html, css, ace-editor

In my html definition I have 4 `div`s: `wrapper` (container) and 3 inner aligned vertically:

```css
    #wrapper {
      width: 80%;
      height: 90vh;
      margin-top: 5vh;
      margin-left: 10%;
      margin-right: 10%;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
    background-color: #e2e2e2;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow:0 10px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19) !important;
    }

    div.editor {
      width: 100%;
      height: 60%;
    }

    #header {
      width: 100%;
      height: 15%;
      min-height: 75px;
    }

    #footer {
      width: 100%;
      height: 25%;
      min-height: 108px;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      justify-content: center;
      /* Centering y-axis */
      flex-flow: row nowrap;
      align-items: center;
    }
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css">
<title>Web Editor</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
        <h1>Web Editor</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="editor" id="editor"></div>
    <div id="footer">
    </div>
</div>
<script src="//ajaxorg.github.io/ace-builds/src-min-noconflict/ace.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script>
    var editor = ace.edit("editor");
    editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
    editor.session.setMode("ace/mode/javascript");
</script>
</body>
```

`min-height` works fine for the `header` but does not work for the `footer` - can shrink to zero. What is the problem? How to solve?

Comment: You'll find that more people will be able to help you if you provide the HTML output instead of the Pug source code.

Comment: What does [tag:ace-editor] have to do with this? Are you trying to style it? Is it rewriting your CSS? You haven't included any JS code that would load it. You should provide a [mcve], preferably in the form of a [live demo](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). If Ace Editor isn't relevant, don't mention it. If it is, provide the code so we can see what it is doing.

Comment: @Quentin, question is edited, code snippet added. Seems ace editor is not the issue: reproducible with default empty div.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/0o1mrapd/25/ your code works. maybe there are some styles from the theme that override your custom styles

Comment: @MihaiT, hmm, yes works, strange. Could footer content be the cause?!

Comment: i can't know unless you replicate your problem exactly

Comment: @MihaiT, After adding marker colors to the divs it was hard to understand the cause: problem is footer div does not have background and therefore looked like shrinked on small screen height. Need to add grey background to it or put outside wrapper.

Comment: so the problem does not exist , that's what you are trying to say ?

Comment: @MihaiT, problem is different: not in div height, but in its style: how div looks like.

Comment: the fact that the footer 'looked' like it was shrinking is not a problem. Not for SO anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding marker colors to the divs it was hard to understand the cause:
problem is `footer` div does not have background and therefore looked like shrinked on small screen height. Need to add grey background to it or put outside wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

Please change footer background colour or wrapper background colour and try to reduce height less then min-height.You can check that min-height is applying.